# In HiveQL how to force the drop of a database with a table referenced by a materialized view?

Tags: hive, materialized-views

It fails if I try to do a `DROP CASCADE` in a database that is referenced by a [materialized view](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+ddl#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/AlterMaterializedView) in another database.

How do I force to delete the database?